# There is a device Android TV in Android Virtual Device Manager, why adb devices do not list?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

In my Android Studio 3.5.3's Android Virtual Device Manager, there already have a device:
[image]

but when I run `adb devices` command in my Terminal, there is no device list:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

Answer (score 0):

`adb devices` lists attached devices and *running* emulator images. The AVD Manager lists *defined* emulator images.

To run an emulator image, click the green triangle in its AVD Manager row. Then, after the emulator appears, `adb devices` should return an entry for it.